# Mathaccent in math mode

Tags: math-mode, equations, texstudio, accents, specials

I wrote the following line of codes:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis} % Paper size, default font size and one-sided paper
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem,kantlipsum}
\usepackage{breqn}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}
\graphicspath{{./Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored
\usepackage[top=2.1in, bottom=0.3in, left=2.2in, right=0.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{equation}
pr(X,\c{S}\big|\varPi\big) = pr(\c{s}_1|\tau\big)\prod_{n=2}^N pr(\c{s}_n \big|{\c{s}}_{n-1}, Tr_{pr}\big) \prod_{n=1}^N pr\big({x}_n \big|{\c{s}}_{n}, \textbf{E}\big) 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I try to run the above but I am having this error **Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode pr(X,\c{S}\big|\varPi\big) = pr(\c{s}_** The 'cedilla' sign is my problem. In maths mode $\c{S}$ work but in equation mode, it doesn't work.

Interestingly, it works in another template as shown below

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\newcommand{\mdash}{\mathinner{\relbar\joinrel\relbar\joinrel\relbar}}
\modulolinenumbers[1]

\begin{document}
    HMM's joint probability distribution over both hidden and observed variables is defined by:
\begin{equation}
    pr(X,\c{S}\big|\varPi\big) = pr(\c{s}_1|\tau\big)\prod_{n=2}^N pr(\c{s}_n \big|{\c{s}}_{n-1}, Tr_{pr}\big) \prod_{n=1}^N pr\big({x}_n \big|{\c{s}}_{n}, \textbf{E}\big) 
    \end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The cedilla isn't defined as a math accent, but you can get it by using `\textit{\c{S}}` (or `\textrm` if the S should be upright).  Also, `hyperref` should be the last package loaded (with a few exceptions, but I didn't see them in your list).

Comment: Okay but it works for this template:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `\c` “works” in the second case is due to loading `txfonts` (that nobody can recommend, because of several shortcomings in font metrics). You still get

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \c invalid in math mode on input line 21.
```

and what you get doesn't match the rest of the formula, because it's typeset in math mode.

[image]

The same with `newtx` instead

[image]

which is slightly better, but still has several typographic shortcomings.

1. “pr” is an operator
2. the vertical bar should be spaced (and not `\big`)
3. “Tr” seems to be a single name for a function
4. `\textbf{E}` should be `\mathbf{E}`
5. `\big` should be used consistently and become `\bigl` for opening, `\bigm` for “middle” relations and `\bigr` for closing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtx}

\DeclareMathOperator{\pr}{pr}
\newcommand{\cs}{\textnormal{\itshape\c{s}}}
\newcommand{\cS}{\textnormal{\itshape\c{S}}}
\newcommand{\Tr}{\mathit{Tr}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \pr(X,\cS \mid \varPi) = 
  \pr(\cs_1 \mid \tau)
  \prod_{n=2}^N \pr(\cs_n \mid \cs_{n-1}, \Tr_{\pr})
  \prod_{n=1}^N \pr(x_n \mid \cs_{n}, \mathbf{E})
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @egreg